# How do I display, in a ColorBox popup, a caption AND a title (caption from image 'alt' attribute and title from 'title' attribute

Tags: 7, javascript

I am trying to display in a ColorBox popup, a caption AND a title (caption from image 'alt' attribute and title from image 'title' attribute).
The colorbox is opened when an image is clicked.

Here is an example of what I want to do.

> [image: screenshot]

The img will be something like the following.

```
<img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost:4444/img.jpg" width="336"   height="254" alt="LEGEND / CAPTION balbalblalblalba balbalblalblalba balbalblalblalba" title="TITLE balbalblalblalba balbalblalblalba balbalblalblalba" class="">
```

Do you have any idea of how can I do that?

I am using:

- Colorbox 7.x-2.10
- Drupal 7.35

The colorbox module settings are the following.

> [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Add "colorbox" class to your element. You could also select by `document.getElementsByTagName("img")`, but we don't really want to select every single img tag.

```
var cbox = document.getElementsByClassName("colorbox")

for (var i=0, i < cbox.length; i++) {
  cboxTitle = cbox[i].title;
  cboxAlt= cbox[i].alt;

  cboxTitle = "<span class='title'>" + cboxTitle + "</span> <span class='alt'>" + cboxAlt + "</span>"
}
```

You then just got to make colorbox print out the title tag and style it the way you want.